# Пуш содержимого без папки

Tags: git, github, gitignore, push

**Реально пушить содержимое build/ без самой папки?** 
Push в своей рабочей копии хранилища.
build/ в корне, на одном уровне с .git и .gitignore.

Comment: A где эта папка находится? Добавте больше информации в вопрос.

Comment: В корне, на одном уровне с .git и .gitignore

Comment: Добавте информацию прямо в вопрос.

Comment: push/pull — это всего лишь синхронизация содержимого хранилищ. поэтому пока неясно, чего именно вы хотите добиться: а) в своей рабочей копии хранилища; б) в рабочих копиях тех, кто вместе с вами пользуется транзитым хранилищем. изложите это, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну для полноты картины *Git* не знает ничего про ваши папки. Хранятся только файлы, одним свойством которых есть путь.